# Unable to find the controller for path (Symfony tutorial)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, content-management-system

I am following online tutorial for Symfony CMS:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/tutorial/introduction.html

On the final page the routing is created ( I am sorry i can not paste the link of this tutorial page, because StackOverflow blocks number of links)

But i am not able to view any of pages. Where i should search for the mistake? Actually, debug:router does not lists any url with posts. But `doctrine:phpcr:node:dump` lists nodes with posts. Tutorials offers to check the following url:
`localhost:8000/page/home`

Bot of them gives `ERROR: Unable to find the controller for path "/page/home". The route is wrongly configured. 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException`

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS>php app/console doctrine:phpcr:node:dump
ROOT:
  cms:
    routes:
      page:
        home:
      post:
        2015-10-14:
          my-first-post:
          my-second-post:
          my-third-post:
          my-fourth-post:
    pages:
      Home:
    posts:
      My First Post:
      My Second Post:
      My Third Post:
      My Fourth Post:


c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS>php app/console debug:router
[router] Current routes
 Name                     Method Scheme Host Path
 _wdt                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
 _profiler_home           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
 _profiler_search         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search
 _profiler_search_bar     ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar
 _profiler_purge          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge
 _profiler_info           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}
 _profiler_phpinfo        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo
 _profiler_search_results ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results
 _profiler                ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}
 _profiler_router         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router
 _profiler_exception      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception
 _profiler_exception_css  ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 _configurator_home       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
 _configurator_step       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}
 _configurator_final      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final
 _twig_error_test         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_error/{code}.{_format}
 acme_basic_cms_homepage  ANY    ANY    ANY  /hello/{name}
 homepage                 ANY    ANY    ANY  /
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS\app\config\routing.yml

```
acme_basic_cms:
    resource: "@AcmeBasicCmsBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /  
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS\src\Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

```
acme_basic_cms_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBasicCmsBundle:Default:index }
```

But there is one more routing file, which as far as i understand is not louded to the simpleCMS\app\config\routing.yml. It is 
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS\src\Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Resources\config\cmf_routing_auto.yml

## src/Acme/BasicCmsBundle/Resources/config/cmf_routing_auto.yml

```
Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Document\Page:
    uri_schema: /page/{title}
    token_providers:
        title: [content_method, { method: getTitle }]

Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Document\Post:
    uri_schema: /post/{date}/{title}
    token_providers:
        date: [content_datetime, { method: getDate }]
        title: [content_method, { method: getTitle }]
```

Maybe i have to add this "simpleCMS\src\Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Resources\config\cmf_routing_auto.yml" to the "simpleCMS\app\config\routing.yml".

Comment: Check whether you imported all necessary routes in `app/config/routing.yml`.

Comment: I am sorry, seems this was not the last page of the tutorial. I will comment later than i finish it. Speaking about the routes, seems that C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS\src\Acme\BasicCmsBundle\Resources\config\cmf_routing_auto.yml is not inported to the  C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\simpleCMS\app\config\routing.yml. I have pasted the content of both files above.